# Using ffmpeg codec inside Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ffmpeg

I've been struggling with this topic for the past few weeks and I am yet to find a way to use ffmpeg inside my Xamarin project. There are couple of C# wrappers that work great but they don't work for API 15 and below versions of Android.

I'm trying to use ffmpeg in my project but I really don't know how to. I have tried to bind a Java project I found but .jar binding didn't work and apparently the only way is to use JNI for the binding which isn't very easy to do, at least for me.

I'm hoping someone can provide me some sources I can read on and understand how it works and what ways I can use ffmpeg in my project.

I will really appreciate any kind of help I can get.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I'm thinking JNI via the Android NDK is the best way to go if you can't find a good wrapper. Are you sure you need API level <=15 support?

Comment: My device uses API 15 and this wrapper I found here : https://github.com/leye0/XamarinAndroidFFmpeg doesn't work properly on my device. I have tested it with other devices with API above 15 and it seems to work fine on all of them though the developer of this project said that it should support Android 2.0 even but he's currently on a vacation so he said he'll look into it once he gets back. I'm gonna do some reading on how to use JNI. any good resources in your mind?

Comment: This is where it gets hard. There are few good, up-to-date resources for getting started with JNI and the Android NDK. You will probably have to do a little research on the basics of the Android NDK yourself as I cannot think of any good resources atm. Assuming that you know C / C++, your using Visual Studio, and can figure out the NDK, this article may prove helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/02/23/developing-xamarin-android-native-applications/

Comment: Thank you! I do know C/C++ but I'm relatively new to Android and Java. It's amazing how something so simple as using a codec library can be so difficult due to the lack of platform support.